# Code Contract: malformed when incapsulate require method and unable to use String.Format

Tags: c#, code-contracts, malformed

It seems that CodeContract from DevLab is a nice tool, but I had two errors in with code:

```
public class SomeClass
{
   private DataTable _dataTable

   // I don't want to write the same condition more then ones, so incapsulate it
   private void CheckRowIndex(int rowIndex)
   {
      //Error1 in next line: User message to contract call can only be string literal, or a static
      // field, or static property that is at least internally visible.    
      Contract.Requires<IndexOutOfRangeException>(_dataTable.Rows.Count >= rowIndex + 1,
        String.Format("There is no row with index {0} in table.", rowIndex));
   }

   public object GetObject(int rowIndex, int colIndex)
   {
     // Error2 in next line: malformed contract
     CheckRowIndex();
     return _dataTable.Rows[rowIndex][colIndex];
   }
   public object GetObject(int rowIndex, string colName)
   {
     CheckRowIndex();
     return _dataTable.Rows[rowIndex][colName];
   }
}
```

Are there any techniques how to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [point #1 have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642857/codecontracts-reuse-of-assumptions-asserts)

Contract overloads taking a `userMessage` such as [Requires(bool condition, string userMessage)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990900(v=vs.110).aspx) require that the `userMessage` message be a literal, or static (e.g. `static readonly`), or `const`, as per the error message.

Since the user message is for you, the developer, not for users why not just make it generic:

```
String.Format("There is no row with this index in the table");
```

There's more of a discussion on what to put in the (IMO badly named) [userMessage parameter here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27017165/314291)

Comment: Thank you. There is no way to find first post that you get me by using error message.